# Bypass SSL validation in ASP.NET core in Linux

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, ubuntu-16.04, kestrel-http-server

Our client has an on premise hosting of Cloud foundry that runs using a self signed certificate. We are developing MicroServices for him in ASP.NET Core. During this we need to make non-encrypted HTTP calls for which we are using HttpClient.

- *Is there way I can bypass the SSL validation check in SSL client for
  Ubuntu (I know it can be done for windows)?*

I know there are some previous answer but those are not providing any resolution. Hence please do not mark this questions as duplicate

Comment: Do you mean that you need to add that self signed certificate to the Trusted Root Certificates in the client machines (ubuntu)?

Comment: No I just want to skip the validation of Server certificate. There is winHttpHandler. what is the equivalent for the for Linux machines

Answer (score 2):

You can use the certificate validation callback of the HttpClientHandler like this :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler())
    using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
    {
        handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback += (message, xcert, chain, errors) => true;

        var result =  client.GetStringAsync("https://self-signed.badssl.com/").Result;
        Console.WriteLine(result.Substring(0, 100));
    }
}
```

Tested with Bash on Ubuntu on Windows

Answer (score 0):

CurlHandler class looks like Unix equivalent of WinHttpHandler. Reference: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/tree/30f2f877c01940904b85691a09da5f91352ffad9/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/Unix

Answer (score 0):

Customizing handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback on a System.Net.Http HttpClientHandler does the trick.